# Barrel with slot, that can slide

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, actuator

[image]

Image sourced from: [Huygens optics YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@HuygensOptics/videos) : [Maskless Wafer Stepper Part 2: Mechanics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdRwiI6VLmk) @ [7:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdRwiI6VLmk&t=460s)

I need to couple a stepper motor to a leadscrew that will be translating back and forth. One solution that I saw online is to have a barrel with a slot, and have a notch coming out of a disk attached to the motor shaft that rotates the barrel.

Is this a standard part? If so, what is it called?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=collapsible+drive+shaft&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @Ansh - a link would be useful to save having to search for it... as well as the time that the image appears. The more info that you can provide, the easier it will be (and people will be more inclined) to answer the question. I have added those for you.

Comment: I think generally anything that converts rotation to translation on a leadscrew is generally called a [leadscrew nut](https://www.mcmaster.com/lead-screw-nuts/) (no affiliation with McMaster, they're just awesome)